# How can i determine if a site 404'd in javascript and then redirect the browser somewhere else

Tags: javascript, redirect, greasemonkey

I am trying to write a greasemonkey script for firefox that will check a site on opening and see if the website 404'd and then redirect the user automatically somewhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Redirect
// @namespace      test
// @include        *
// ==/UserScript==

if (/^about:neterror/.test(document.documentURI))
{
    location.assign(...);
}
```

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work in many cases, because many (¿most?) servers respond with an HTML page for their 404's. Also, Greasemonkey no longer fires on `about:` pages.

Answer (score 2):

Make an AJAX request to the URI and check the response code from the returned XHR object for the 404 error code (or != 200).

Do you have access to some kind of JS Framework?

Comment: You don't need a JS Framework to make an XHR call in GM: http://diveintogreasemonkey.org/api/gm_xmlhttprequest.html

Comment: If by "site", you mean some other domain, you can't do this with XHR due to the "same origin policy", i.e. cross-site scripting security restrictions

Answer (score 0):

By "check a site", I assume you mean a url on a different domain.

This can't be done strictly from the client side without "cooperation" from the target service due to client side cross-site security restrictions, and I imagine that is not your use case.

A common solution is to use some kind of server side proxy.

If you use a page on your site to act as the proxy, you can make it flexible enough to accept requests to check any URL.

- make a resource page on your site, e.g. checkRemotePage.php
- checkRemotePage.php calls the target site's page and obtains response code
- call your page /checkRemotePage.php via ajax to get the data it retrieved

If your needs are limited to a static url or a small list of url prefixes, you can use apache mod_proxy

- enable mod_proxy
- use a ProxyPass entry /check_remote_page http://www.somehost.com/the_rest_of_the_url